Is there any danger in supposing m>n in the Cauchy sequence conditions?
$$\forall \epsilon > 0,\ \text{let} \ N=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\epsilon}}.$$
$$\text{So}, \ m>n>N \implies \frac{1}{m^2}<\epsilon. $$
$$
|s_n-s_m| = \frac{n^2-1}{n^2}-\frac{m^2-1}{m^2}=\frac{1}{m^2}-\frac{1}{n^2} < \frac{1}{m^2} < \epsilon
$$
I am wondering about the definition of the Cauchy sequence and why most of the proofs I see do not assume WLOG $n>m$. In my recent assignment both my proofs immediately assumed $m>n$. Above is a shortened example. However, the proof presented in class and others I have seen online (for this problem and others) generally seem to avoid doing this. I'm pretty sure it's ok (since $|s_n-s_m|=|s_m-s_n|$) but I am wondering if there is some reason it not done more often.

There is no harm in assuming $m>n$, precisely for the reasons you mentioned. Perhaps a conceptual advantage of the usual definition is that it emphasises that $m$ and $n$ play symmetric rôles.

No any danger at all.

I agree with the others, but in your case there is an error, you got the sign of the absolute value wrong: $s_n < s_m$. It doesn't affect the result, because $1/n^2 < \epsilon$ as well.
